# SpringBoot: How to provide VM Argument in Spring Boot App, while running from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-boot, jvm-arguments

I'm Using Spring Boot 1.3.0.RELEASE.
And for my application, I'm providing some external jar path like below, while I'm running the app from CMD.

```
java -Dloader.path="lib,config,C:/TM/ojdbc14-10.2.0.2.0.jar,spring" -jar ticketmanager-application-0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Now, when I'm trying to run the app from eclipse, I'm add the `-Dloader.path="lib,config,C:/TM/ojdbc14-10.2.0.2.0.jar,spring"` to VM Argument. Like the snapshot shown below.

[image]

**Editing: Adding Maven Spring Plugin configuration ------------------------**

Here, the configuration section, I have added for the `loader.path`

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Therefore, my question,
**How should I add this Argument? because it's not working :(**

Comment: You're already added it. So, what is your problem?

Comment: Another thing: why do you use such an ancient Oracle driver ?

Comment: And: what exactly is not working ?

Comment: well, my driver jar, stays outside app.jar, so using loader.path I'm passing the path of the external jar.
Now, this thing is working while executing from CMD
But, not working while using eclipse vm argument, ad running as spring boot app

Comment: Show the code where you use the loader.path ?

Comment: Well, when I'm running from CMD, only running this command `java -Dloader.path="lib,config,C:/TM/ojdbc14-10.2.0.2.0.jar,spring" -jar ticketmanager-application-0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` works.
But, from eclipse, I tried by writing in application.properties file like `loader.path: lib,config,C:/TM/ojdbc14-10.2.0.2.0.jar,spring`. 
And then in eclipse VM argument as, you can see the image, `-Dloader.path=lib,config,C:/TM/ojdbc14-10.2.0.2.0.jar,spring` But both approch doesn't work.
Apart from that, I did'n write any code for this.
And, JDBC, is loading in server startup, from a Spring bean config.

Comment: Are you using the STS version of eclipse? Are you running it as a Spring Boot App?

Comment: If the `loader.path` is being ignored when running through eclipse, you may have to add the jar and folders to the build path like this: right-click/Build Path/Configure Build Path/Libraries

Comment: Yes, @whistling, that way, it is working

Answer (score 3):

*Program arguments*, are arguments that passed to `main` method of your program. Looks like space-separated list of values. Example:

```
java Program arg1 arg2 arg3
```

*VM arguments*, are system properties passed to the Java Virtual Machine in `name=value` format. Examle:

```
java -Dprop1=value1 -Dprop2=value2 Program
```

In your case you need to add *VM arguments* but not *Program arguments*

By the way, according to [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher.html), you can add `loader.path` and `loader.main` properties right in your `application.properties`. Information about how to work with `application.property`, and how to externalize configuration settings you can find [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

Comment: Ok!.. I added loader.path in application.properties, but still its not working. any idea?

Comment: @anij first, try to pass `loader.path` thru VM arguments. I don't know, why yours `application.properties` does not work. mine works well. pleas check that you put `application.properties` into proper place.

Comment: yes I have placed the application.properties, in proper place, because, I'm also reffering other properties from application.properties as `-Dxxx=123` while starting the app from cmd or linux.
I have placed the config like this 
`loader.path = lib,config,c:/ojdbc14-10.2.0.2.0.jar` in the top of the file. but it's not working.

Comment: From CMD mode: both loader.path & other properties also working like defining port & all, but from Eclipse VM argument setting others are working.. only loader.path is not working